# Tools to troubleshoot and view raw HTTP Requests

Tags: http, arduino, http-post, httprequest, iot

I am writing code that will let Arduino sent http posts to a IOT cloud service (thethings.io). The Arduino (Adafruit Trinket Pro 3v) uses AT commands to control a cellular module (Adafruit FONA 3G). The AT commands specify http headers and body of the http post. The server I am calling is returning 400 bad request, but it does not echo back to me the actual HTTP request so that I can see what is malformed. What ways are there to view the raw output of an HTTP request? Sites/services/tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't to debug the http request from your code, you can use online cloud tools like:

- https://requestb.in/
- https://mockbin.org/

And inspect the request from their services.